# SAS Reading CSV File--Error : Open code statement recursion detected

Tags: sas

I need to read a csv file in SAS EG using the following code:

```
proc import datafile='\\...\Trades.csv'
out=Transactions
dbms=csv
replace;
run;
```

However, I get an error saying " ERROR: Open code statement recursion detected."

It is highly appreciated if anyone can help fix the issue. Thanks

Comment: You need to show more information.  Show the first 2 or three lines of text from the CSV file.  (Do NOT open the CSV file with a spreadsheet program. Open with a text editor and copy the text of the lines.)

Comment: Instead of just giving the error, please past the log here.

Comment: It should not be this kind of error if you only submit the above code. Try restart SAS and submit your import code again.